# is it possible to get credentials from webclient (IE) to activex object in order to upload files to SharePoint WebService?

Tags: sharepoint, activex

As the title.
I create a web part on SharePoint including an ActiveX control. The ActiveX control uses c#. Is it possible to pass the current credentials of IE to ActiveX control and so ActiveX control can upload files to SharePoint without typing username and password again ?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

When the ActiveX control is initialized you can set a property for System.Net.ICredentials with [DefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Once you have this property set you can attach the credentials instance to your web service call.